# iOS SSL User Certificate Mutual Authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl, certificate

I am needing to perform certificate based SSL Mutual auth within an iOS app. The problem I'm having is that when I get the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` I'm having to `useCredential` with an `NSURLCredential` that contains the certificate with the private key.

In my scenario, I cannot send in the private key as it is stored on an external secure token. I can send the certificate, but not the private key. I will therefore need to perform the crypto operations in the secure token, but I haven't been able to figure out where these operations are being performed and which classes I need to override to implement this.

Therefore where and what do I need to do to be able to perform Client Certificate based SSL Mutual Auth when can't create an `NSURLCredential` with the private key?